# Ubuntu-restricted-extras conflict: feature or bug?

Tags: 12.04, dependencies, libraries, ubuntu-restricted-extras

On a fresh 12.04 installation I wanted to install the ubuntu-restricted-extras.
Therefore it needs to remove libavutil51 and libavcodec53.
So, as there will be installed libavutil-extra-51 and libavcodec-extra-53, is it a simple substitution or is it a dependency bug, a conflict between the two versions...?
Thanks.

PS: btw, what's the difference between the 'normal' and the 'extra' version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a simple substitution.nothing else
The difference between normal and extra is that the extra ones do not comply with the open source policy. there are some  patent and copyright restrictions associated with them thus installing them is separately required. check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) for more details