# To install Ubuntu restricted extras, these items must be removed

Tags: apt, ubuntu-restricted-extras, libav

when I want to install Ubuntu `restricted extras`, it says that

> to install Ubuntu restricted extras, these items must be removed: Libav codec library `libavcodec54`.

I want to know that what will happen if the `libavcodec54` moved? If it will generate some errors in my system?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does ubuntu-restricted-extras want to remove some libav packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153884/why-does-ubuntu-restricted-extras-want-to-remove-some-libav-packages)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to worry about the message. From [this guide](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/install-codecs-dvd-playback-ubuntu-1410/):

> Tip: If you get a warning dialog says “to install ubuntu restricted
>   extras, these items must be removed”, just click the ignore because
>   -extra versions of these libraries will be installed instead, to provide additional functionality.